# How to know the release version for a commit in android source?

Tags: git, android-source, repo

Now I have a code file/fragment,  I can search it through google.

So I know the commit.

For example, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/ad76c85%5E!/

However, I want to get the realase version of aosp of the code to sync locally.
What shoud i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out in which branches/tags this commit exist.
Usually every release version gets a tag so simply search it using:

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```

you can read more about it [here](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2012/06/git-pro-tip-how-to-list-tags-that-contain-a-commit-with-git/) and get some other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the commit sha value then you can use "git describe --contains ", this will give you the version in which this commit went in and you can use this version to sync.